# JqGrid get values GridData from Ajax

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, jqgrid

I would pick the values ​​sidx, Sord, page and rows of a jqgrid any, using a function of my JQuery.

example:

```
jQuery ("# grid")
 .navGrid ('# pager', {edit: false, add: false, del: false, search: false})
 .navButtonAdd ('# pager, {
      caption: "Excel"
      id: "grid_mybutton"
      buttonicon "icon_excel"
      onClickButton: function () {
        ExportarExcep ($controler, $sidx, $sord, $page, $rows);
          }
      position: "last"
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understand what you need you can just get `page`, `rowNum`, `sortname` and `sortorder` option of jqGrid and use it as the parameters of your `ExportarExcep` method:

```
jQuery("#grid").jqGrid("navButtonAdd", "#pager", {
      caption: "Excel",
      id: "grid_mybutton",
      //buttonicon "icon_excel",
      onClickButton: function () {
          var p = $(this).jqGrid("getGridParam");
          alert("page=" + p.page +
                ", rows=" + p.rowNum +
                ", sidx=" + p.sortname +
                ", sord=" + p.sortorder);
          //ExportarExcep ($controler, p.sortname, p.sortorder, p.page, p.rowNum);
      },
      position: "last"
});
```

You should be carefully in the syntax of the code which you posted. Your current code contains many syntax errors.